# How can I fix a bootstrap version mismatch when loading Perl's threads module?

Tags: perl, multithreading

I am trying to use threads in Perl, but I get the following errors when I do `require threads`:

```
~ > perl -e 'require threads'
threads object version 1.07 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.71 at /System/Library/Perl/5.8.8/darwin-thread-multi-2level/XSLoader.pm line 94.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
```

I am using OS X 10.5.7 and the default installation of Perl. Do I neeed to reinstall Perl, the threads module, or something?

Comment: A security update a while earlier this year produced this kind of symptom and was later fixed.  Are you up to date?

Comment: Do you have, or have you had in the past, a perl install other than your current one?

Comment: Did you install threads correctly (for. with CPAN shell)?

Comment: You might want to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040323/perl-modules-not-loading-correctly-when-running-as-non-root-user  I was having a similar issue and we found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, some of your files got out of sync.   One way to get it back in sync would be to "force install" the 'threads' module.

I usually use the perl install from MacPorts so I don't mess with the system Perl.

That being said; more likely than not you'll be happier if you don't use threads.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Most "we need threads" problems are better solved with event programming or good 'ol forking.