# Perl modules not loading correctly when running as non-root user

Tags: perl, module, cpan

I'm running into an issue with Perl on a linux system.

When installing new modules (as root), I would occasionally have issues where running scripts as a regular user, I would not be able to access the new module without manually going in and chmod 775'ing the module related files and directories.

I recently performed a CPAN upgrade, as well as installing several modules for a new project.  Now, Perl has become almost unusable as a regular user, because of errors that don't appear to be permissions related.

For example, the following very simple script runs fine as root, but returns an error run as a regular user:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util;
```

As you can see, the script literally does nothing except attempt to load the Scalar::Util module.  As a regular user, it returns this error:

```
**List::Util object version 1.21 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.42 at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 223.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Scalar/Util.pm line 22.
Compilation failed in require at ./scalar-test.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./scalar-test.pl line 4**
```

When I *sudo cpan* and try *install List::Util*, I get back:
    **List::Util is up to date (1.42).**

**CLARIFICATION:**  *This is happening with several modules, not just the one example. It does not appear to affect every module that was upgraded though; it's several though.*

The fact that root can run the scripts says to me that either there is another, underlying permissions issue I'm not seeing, OR PERL is configured slightly different in some way for root than my regular account which is causing it not to find this module.

A search for the List.pm file is returning:

```
 » sudo find / -name List.pm 

/usr/share/perl5/I18N/LangTags/List.pm
/opt/OV/nonOV/perl/a/lib/5.8.8/I18N/LangTags/List.pm
/root/.cpan/build/perl-5.22.1-D0_eFO/dist/I18N-LangTags/lib/I18N/LangTags/List.pm

 » ls -l /usr/share/perl5/I18N/LangTags/List.pm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28826 Nov  6  2014 /usr/share/perl5/I18N/LangTags/List.pm

 » ls -l /opt/OV/nonOV/perl/a/lib/5.8.8/I18N/LangTags/List.pm
-r--r--r-- 1 bin bin 28826 Nov 30  2012 /opt/OV/nonOV/perl/a/lib/5.8.8/I18N/LangTags/List.pm

 » sudo ls -l /root/.cpan/build/perl-5.22.1-D0_eFO/dist/I18N-LangTags/lib/I18N/LangTags/List.pm
-r--r--r-- 1 1018 513 28826 Oct 17 08:32 /root/.cpan/build/perl-5.22.1-D0_eFO/dist/I18N-LangTags/lib/I18N/LangTags/List.pm
```

System is RHEL 6.6 x64, Perl is v5.10.1

---

```
**» type perl**
perl is hashed (/usr/bin/perl)

**» which perl**
/usr/bin/perl 

**» sudo type perl**
sudo: type: command not found 

**» sudo which perl**
/usr/bin/perl

**» echo ${!PERL*}**
[Nothing Returned] 

**» sudo echo ${!PERL*}**
[Nothing Returned]

**» perl -wle 'print join("\n", @INC)'**
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 
/usr/local/share/perl5 
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/lib64/perl5 
/usr/share/perl5 
[run with sudo returns identical list]

[Edited for brevity] 
cpan[1]> o conf 
$CPAN::Config options from /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Config.pm: 
build_dir [/root/.cpan/build] 
build_dir_reuse [0] 
build_requires_install_policy [ask/yes] 
connect_to_internet_ok [1] 
cpan_home [/root/.cpan] 
keep_source_where [/root/.cpan/sources] 
make [/usr/bin/make] 
make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make] 
makepl_arg [INSTALLDIRS=site] 
prefer_installer [MB] 
prefs_dir [/root/.cpan/prefs]
```

I redacted a few lines here from other user's folders

```
 » sudo find / -name Util.pm | grep "List/Util.pm"
/usr/lib64/perl5/List/Util.pm
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/List/Util.pm
/home/{USERNAME REDACTED}/.cpanm/work/1448660183.31550/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.10/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/List/Util.pm
/root/.cpan/build/Scalar-List-Utils-1.42-2c3ONp/lib/List/Util.pm
/root/.cpan/build/Scalar-List-Utils-1.42-2c3ONp/blib/lib/List/Util.pm
/root/.cpan/build/Scalar-List-Utils-1.42-NOwU0A/lib/List/Util.pm
/root/.cpan/build/Scalar-List-Utils-1.42-NOwU0A/blib/lib/List/Util.pm
/root/.cpan/build/perl-5.22.1-D0_eFO/cpan/Scalar-List-Utils/lib/List/Util.pm
```

Per request of brian d foy, I installed a new module.  This module Config::Onion was not previously installed, so nothing old to conflict. The module installs OK, but I created an onion-test.pl script, same as above, and it has the same issue where it only loads the module as root.

```
 » sudo perl -MConfig::Onion -e 'print "Module: " . $ARGV[0] . "\nVersion: " . $ARGV[0]->VERSION . "\n\n"' Config::Onion
Can't locate Config/Onion.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

 » sudo cpan
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.10)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install Config::Onion

[Redacted for brevity. No errors noted during this process.]

Result: PASS
  DSHEROH/Config-Onion-1.004.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Prepending /root/.cpan/build/Config-Onion-1.004-TigyuT/blib/arch /root/.cpan/build/Config-Onion-1.004-TigyuT/blib/lib to PERL5LIB for 'install'
Manifying 2 pod documents
Installing /usr/local/share/perl5/Config/Onion.pm
Installing /usr/local/share/perl5/Config/Onion/Simple.pm
Installing /usr/local/share/man/man3/Config::Onion.3pm
Installing /usr/local/share/man/man3/Config::Onion::Simple.3pm
Appending installation info to /usr/lib64/perl5/perllocal.pod
  DSHEROH/Config-Onion-1.004.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK

 » cd /usr/local/share/perl5/Config
 » sudo ls -l  Onion
total 4
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1856 May  9  2014 Simple.pm

 » sudo find / -name Onion.pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Config/Onion.pm
/root/.cpan/build/Config-Onion-1.004-TigyuT/lib/Config/Onion.pm
/root/.cpan/build/Config-Onion-1.004-TigyuT/blib/lib/Config/Onion.pm


onion-test.pl:

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::Onion;



 » ./onion-test.pl
Can't locate Hash/Merge/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/Config/Onion.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Config/Onion.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at ./onion-test.pl line 29.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./onion-test.pl line 29.


 » sudo ./onion-test.pl
[No Errors]
```

Per Ikegami, I ran this command:

```
sudo chmod -R go+rX                   \
   /usr/local/lib64/perl5        \
   /usr/local/share/perl5        \
   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl  \
   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl  \
   /usr/lib64/perl5              \
   /usr/share/perl5
```

Both of my test scripts, with Scalar::Util and Config::Onion are loading the modules without error.  I think his solution is the right one for the issue I was having, and I've marked it accordingly.  Thanks everyone for your research, and to Ikegami for hitting on the solution.

Comment: Is the $PERL5LIB variable set?

Comment: No, it is not set.  I checked with and without SUDO, and it doesn't show up under root either.  I have sudo access, but I'm not the primary or original sysadmin for the server.  I assume they just did a standard install of PERL during the original OS install.  Perhaps some steps were not completed?

Comment: Try running `type perl` or `which perl` as both users, too.

Comment: Also, show any env variables related to Perl: `echo ${!PERL*}` to get their names in bash.

Comment: Re " I would not be able to access the new module without manually going in and chmod 775'ing the module related files and directories.", hmmm. Perl installers already do that.

Comment: On other computers, I've never had an issue.  Install a cpan module as root, the users can all use it.  On this computer, I've had two different modules that I installed earlier, where I could only use them as root until I went in and increased the permissions.  This system is running an older version of PERL, something that I cannot change at the moment.  When I installed the new modules and did a module upgrade, I assumed it was the same deal with permissions, but in this case, that doesn't seem to be the primary cause.  I chmod'ed the updated files, and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: For context, I should explain that this is a development server in a corporate environment.  Getting the admin team to upgrade PERL would be incredibly difficult.  It might be easier to ask them to create a new VM running RHEL 7.x, which would give me a fresh system with a newer version of PERL by default.

Comment: `sudo echo ${!PERL*}` expands the variable names before running sudo.

Comment: I tried **printenv | grep perl** with and without sudo, returned nothing either.  Reviewing full printenv output showed nothing PERL related.

Comment: @ByronJones: Please, it's ***Perl***.

Comment: Borodin: Noted.        **» perl -wle 'print join("\n", @INC)'**
/usr/local/lib64/perl5     
/usr/local/share/perl5   
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl    
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl    
/usr/lib64/perl5    
/usr/share/perl5      [run with sudo returns identical list]

Comment: Check your CPAN config by running `o conf` in the CPAN shell.

Comment: Add clarifying information to the question, not the comments.

Comment: Brian - Noted.   I'll move it.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251918/how-can-i-fix-a-bootstrap-version-mismatch-when-loading-perls-threads-module , but that doesn't have a satisfying answer.

Comment: You're right, it seems like these probably have the same root cause.  I'll post a link from this one into that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List/Util/Util.so` probably exists twice in

```
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 
/usr/local/share/perl5 
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/lib64/perl5 
/usr/share/perl5
```

They are different versions. The newer one can only be accessed by root. If this is the problem it will be solved using

```
chmod -R go+rX                   \
   /usr/local/lib64/perl5        \
   /usr/local/share/perl5        \
   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl  \
   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl  \
   /usr/lib64/perl5              \
   /usr/share/perl5
```

Comment: I ran this command, and the errors with Scalar::Util and Config::Onion both went away when running as non root. I'll keep testing, but I think this may have resolved the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*I can only get so far on the information you provide, but here's a start. If you fill in some details we may be able to figure out this problem.*

These sorts of error typically mean that you have two versions of the same module installed in different places or that the it was upgraded incompletely in one place (perhaps because someone tried it by hand, had insufficient permissions, or was interrupted). The program is able to load one part of the module from one source, fails to load a second part and looks elsewhere. Hence you get the mismatch.

In your case, it looks like you have `List::Util` in both */usr/lib64/perl5* and
*/usr/local/lib64/perl5*. From your `@INC`, you look in */usr/local/lib64/perl5* first. I'm guessing that's where the newest version should be. For some reason, it doesn't load right so it keeps looking and finds the old version in */usr/lib64/perl5*, but that's a mismatch.

For pure Perl files, these matches don't usually matter. However, for the compiled (XS) modules, the details of their compilation have to match up. Different versions of the same compilation tools, or different inputs to the same versions, likely cause incompatible formats. Or, different versions of the same Perl module name might have been reorganized so they don't match up with the binary component of previous versions. Hence the error message you get after something else already went wrong.

I wonder in your case if you've set an odd umask so that your root module installation doesn't make the file readable (or the directory executable) so other users can see the files. What were the permissions before you changed them? You should track down that problem since you said you've had the same problem previously (and may again).

The `cpan` module can find it for you looking through the current Perl's `@INC`. I haven't upgraded `List::Util` on this version of Perl, and it's found under *lib/5.22.0/darwin-2level*:

```
$ cpan -D List::Util
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.53)
Reading '/Users/brian/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 26 Jan 2016 12:17:02 GMT
List::Util
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    List utilities (eg min, max, reduce)
    P/PE/PEVANS/Scalar-List-Utils-1.42.tar.gz
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/5.22.0/darwin-2level/List/Util.pm
    Installed: 1.41
    CPAN:      1.42  Not up to date
    Graham Barr (GBARR)
    gbarr@pobox.com
```

After I update it, the update is in *lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level*, a different directory. CPAN.pm does not remove old versions, it merely shadows them. I still have the version that originally came with your Perl, and now you have an update in *site_perl*

```
$ cpan -D List::Util
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.53)
Reading '/Users/brian/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 26 Jan 2016 12:17:02 GMT
List::Util
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20150520)
List utilities (eg min, max, reduce)
    P/PE/PEVANS/Scalar-List-Utils-1.42.tar.gz
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/List/Util.pm
    Installed: 1.42
    CPAN:      1.42  up to date
    Graham Barr (GBARR)
    gbarr@pobox.com
```

The paths may vary from system to system, but the idea is the same. I have different versions in different directories.

Now to recreate the problem. Curiously, in Perl v5.22, when I move the newly installed directory so it doesn't have the right name (forcing Perl to look in the wrong directory), I get a much friendly (although similarly unhelpful) message:

```
$ perl5.22.0 -MScalar::Util -e 1
List::Util version 1.42 required--this is only version 1.41 at /usr/local/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/Scalar/Util.pm line 23.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

It looks like you are using Perl 5.8.8. When I tried this same process on my system, `cpan` wrote files to the same location.

However, you can configure `cpan` for the installation locations. Your system may have helpfully done that for you. If you have the build logs (or `cpan` config or package manager info) to show us where it installed the new `List::Util`, that could help. Or, find us the list of *List/Util.pm* files you have installed and we could work backward. If you installed from a package, that might have chosen another location.

My advice is normally to leave the base installation alone and install everything into a different set of directories. If you are playing with the system `perl` (and it looks like you are), messing up the same `perl` that system needs for its admin and housekeeping tasks can cause additional headaches.

Comment: Brian - Thanks for this very in depth response.  I'm still looking it all over, but in the meantime I'll post the list of List/Util.pm files installed.

Comment: I've added a clarification that this is happening to multiple modules.  While I had seen a permissions issue when I installed new modules previously, this current issue occurred when I installed new modules and did a perl module upgrade.  I did both at the same time, but I am seeing errors with modules that I think were more likely part of the upgrade, rather than installed as a module dependency.  It almost seems like the upgrade had problems, although I did not see anything beyond the usual occasional test warning during the upgrade.

Comment: Brian - There are only two people who use this development server, and it's not a production server in any way.  Perhaps I should have (beg) the sysadmins to completely uninstall and reinstall/update the Perl package for RHEL 6.6?  I'm thinking that a clean slate install might be preferred to chasing down something that might have resulted in a corrupt Perl configuration.  I'm an IT generalist, not a Perl guru...

Comment: Is it possible to install another module as root and show us the permissions it creates? Also, can you show us the umask setting the root account has?

Comment: If it were me, I'd start over and keep a snapshot to go back to. I'm more interested in helping the entire world solve this rare but interesting problem, though. The next person who has this problem can read this answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help Brian.  The chmod that Ikegami suggested above seems to have resolved the issue. The test scripts I wrote are working as non-root now.  I'll keep testing as I continue development, but I think this has resolved the issue.

Comment: Okay, but it's the same thing you were doing before. *shrug*

Comment: Not exactly.  Before I had been chmod'ing individual modules post-install, assuming that the module installer had not set permissions or something.  This was a more comprehensive chmod, which seems to help perl find the correct version when running as non-root. I think the directory permissions were wrong for the module directory itself.  Perhaps whomever setup the system locked down the permissions excessively, and left regular users with this issue of not being able to load modules.

Comment: Just to add; since the module initially in question was Scalar::Util, a dual-life (in core and on CPAN) module, and the perl being used is prior to 5.12.0, "sudo cpan" will actually install the module into the perl's archlib, *overwriting* the original core module. This is because prior to 5.12.0, the @INC order places privlib/archlib before sitelib, so if a dual-life module is installed to sitelib the new version will not be picked up, it will still be masked by the core module. I'm not sure how it figures into the XS issues, but it may be important to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you for this additional information.  While I've used Perl off and on for years as needed, it was never my primary language for work until recently.  I think I'll need to do some more self-learning about what is going on under the hood in Perl, especially for this kind of situation.

Comment: My advice is normally much like Brian's, in that if you plan to do any serious development in Perl and need updated/additional perl modules, you should install your own perl separate from the system perl which is usually managed by a package manager. This is easy to do with tools like [perl-build](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Build/script/perl-build), [perlbrew](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlbrew), and [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv), and you get the option of benefiting from the development on perl core since 5.10.1.

Comment: I considered that.  The concerns I had were:  Several of the scripts I develop are run under a separate service account once they are ready to be scheduled in cron.  Also, I wanted to ensure that if a new employee took over the work on these scripts, that the default environment would allow him to do the work without having to reverse engineer my environment.  My predecessor seems to have had a custom Perl config, but they deleted his user account, so I can't login as him to see how his Perl was configured.

Comment: Those are fair concerns certainly. But if you can ensure the scripts run correctly under the other version of perl, you can usually just change the shebang to point to the newly built version explicitly, or run it explicitly as: /path/to/perl /path/to/script.pl -- this doesn't require any messing about with PATH.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered that.  Perhaps if I setup a separate Perl instance not for me alone, but rather one that was separate from the default system Perl, in my application's own directory, and have an independent configuration.  That way I could install a version of Perl later than the rather dated one that is on the system, and not worry about that system version any more.

Comment: Brian, I just ran across your article http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/03/make-links-to-per-version-tools/  and I will give it a thorough read.  I'm honored that a real Perl Guru helped me today :)

Answer (score 1):

For those, who struggle with this kind of issue, and are running **grsec** linux kernel, check `dmesg -T` for occurences of messages, such as

```
[Thu Jul 13 12:39:32 2017] grsec: From 12.34.56.78: denied untrusted exec (due to file in group-writable directory) of /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so by /usr/bin/perl[perl:9515] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000, parent /bin/bash[bash:31545] uid/euid:1000/1000 gid/egid:1000/1000
```

This means non-root user was not able to use perl shared library `mysql.so` because of permissions on parent folder.

Solution good enough is to (for example, in this particular case) chmod parent folder `g-w` (group -write)

```
chmod g-w /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1/auto/DBD/mysql/
```